# Folder modification time including the files inside it?

Tags: python

currently what I do is:

```
import os

dir = '/var/www/site1.com'
modTime = os.path.getmtime(dir)
```

But the modification time is not as recent as the modification time of the most recent file modified inside that folder. Is there a way to get the mtime of that directory/folder with respect to the files/folder inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without looking at the `mtime` value for each and every file in that folder.

You can use `max()` on the `getmtime` value for each entry in the folder:

```
modTime = max([os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dir, p)) for p in os.listdir(dir)])
```